# Google map is not loading in android samsung ace mobile

Tags: android, google-maps, custom-overlay

i am displaying some locations using Google map in my application, and displaying all locations with custom pins.
Every thing is working fine in emulator but when i tested in Samsung galaxy s and s plus working fine, But in Samsung ace the map is not displayed, i am not able to solve this problem.
How to display the map with locations in Samsung ace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you generate Google Maps API from YOUR Keystore file?

Check it please http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Hope it hepl you!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually i have installed the application from other system, in that system the Keystore file is not there, so again i installed from my system(Keystore file located in my system) it is working fine now, thanks a lot i got the idea from your post